# ScalaTest asserting collection contain a type

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a collection like below

`val buffer: Buffer[Try[E]]`

and I want to assert that within the `buffer` does not contain any `Failure`. Ideally I want to do it like this

`buffer should not contain a[Failure[_]]`

However it doesn't seem that it is checking the type properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify your problem?

The following code compiles and runs

*src/test/scala/Test1.scala*

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers._
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class Test1 extends FlatSpec {

  class E

  val buffer: mutable.Buffer[Try[E]] = ListBuffer(Success(new E), Success(new E))

  buffer should not contain a[Failure[_]]

}
```

---

`a`/`an` is supposed to be used with Exceptions like

```
an [IndexOutOfBoundsException] should be thrownBy s.charAt(-1)
```

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers

Try

```
buffer filter(_.isFailure) should be (empty).
```

Comment: It compiles, and it runs. But it doesn't assert correctly.
Even if you put `buffer should not contain a[Success[_]]`, it will pass

Comment: `a`/`an` is supposed to be used with Exceptions like `an [IndexOutOfBoundsException] should be thrownBy s.charAt(-1)` http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers

Comment: Try `buffer filter(_.isFailure) should be (empty)`.